# group records in 10 seconds interval with min column value with in a partition - Spark or Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I need to group records in 10 seconds interval with min column value as start with in a partition. If record is outside of 10 sec then new group starts. Below is a partition and this needs to be grouped as shown in expecting result.

| Time | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-11 04:20 | va11 |
| 2023-04-11 04:36 | val2 |
| 2023-04-11 04:42 | val3 |
| 2023-04-11 04:44 | val4 |
| 2023-04-11 04:47 | val5 |
| 2023-04-11 04:48 | val6 |
| 2023-04-11 04:51 | val7 |
| 2023-04-11 04:57 | val8 |
| 2023-04-11 05:13 | val9 |

| Time | concateText |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-11 04:20 | val1 |
| 2023-04-11 04:36 | val2 : val3 : val4 |
| 2023-04-11 04:47 | val5 : val6 : val7 : val8 |
| 2023-04-11 05:13 | val9 |

Time in output is min or start of 10 sec interval. first group starts at 4.2 and since there is no other value between 4.2 and 4.3 (10 sec interval) only one value in concatText group. Next group should starts at next time (4.36, not at 4.31) and go next 10 seconds and so on..

There could be any number of records in 10 sec interval. Just one or more than one.

Comment: what is the datatype for time(is it decimal/string) in your example. Sample create table scripts would help

Comment: Changed time to timestamp. Time is timestamp type and text is string  type.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you would need to have a recursive cte. Here is a solution

```
with data 
  as (select row_number() over(order by time_of_day) as rnk
             ,time_of_day
             ,text_val
        from testing_gaps
     )
    ,recursive_block
     as (select  time_of_day as start_time_of_grp
                ,time_of_day
                ,text_val
                ,rnk
           from data
          where rnk=1
         union all
        select case when datediff(second,rb.start_time_of_grp,b.time_of_day)>10 then 
                         b.time_of_day 
                    else rb.start_time_of_grp 
                end as start_time_of_grp
               ,b.time_of_day
               ,b.text_val
               ,b.rnk 
          from recursive_block rb
          join data b
            on rb.rnk+1=b.rnk
          )
select start_time_of_grp as "time"
       ,string_agg(text_val,':') concattext
 from recursive_block 
group by start_time_of_grp
```

Db Fiddle Link

https://dbfiddle.uk/PtbE1o91

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+
|          time           |     concattext      |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2023-04-11 00:04:20.000 | va11                |
| 2023-04-11 00:04:36.000 | val2:val3:val4      |
| 2023-04-11 00:04:47.000 | val5:val6:val7:val8 |
| 2023-04-11 00:05:13.000 | val9                |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: recursive CTEs doesn't work in spark SQL

Comment: You will have to use procedural programming in this case